# How to know a domain is bad before calling SmtpClient.Send()?

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtp

I have code that sends emails to users from a signup webpage.  Occasionally, users will mistype an email address and the address ends up having a bad domain.

I would love to be able to check to see if the domain is bad BEFORE calling the System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send() method since this would lead to a better user experience.  I think using AJAX to tell the user right away their email won't send without having to programmatically send an email before finding out it is bad is much more elegant.

I currently handle the error just fine so please don't discuss how to handle errors.  The error I get is:
"Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: : Recipient address rejected: Domain not found"

Does anyone know of a way that would use similar (or the same exact) code to verify if a domain is bad or not before calling the Send() method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most reliable way to make sure a mail server is actually configured for a given domain is to [query the MX record](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20050129.asp) for that domain.

Comment: The link you refer to works, thanks.  The code uses DllImport though, which I am not too keen on.

Comment: There is probably a 100% managed solution out there if you don't want to reference any unmanaged code.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
string email = "person@domain.com"
MailAddress ma = new MailAddress(email); // Throws exception if email address is incorrectly formatted
System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(ma.Host); // Throws exception if host is invalid
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good article on it: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/validation/Valid_Email_Addresses.aspx

In my experience I just use a regex validator to verify format and use a confirmation type of system to ensure it is a valid address.

UPDATE: That article is old, so I would check to ensure not deprecated.

Comment: But mistyping an email will not always fail a regex validation. Example: myname@mgail.com. +1 for the link though.

Comment: @Joel Potter, that is why I specified the process as a replacement to him goal. The confirmation is a good feature for more than accuracy, it is also useful in eliminating bots.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I already use regex to verify this.  Still doesn't guard against non-existent domains though.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use `System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName(hostname)` and determine if it comes back with something valid?

Although MSDN is telling me that that method is deprecated...

Maybe `System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(hostname)` is it's predecessor?

Comment: Not only that, but mail hosts are not required to have an A record (IP address), only an MX record.